# Leetcode javascript reverse-linked-list，a question about new in javascipt

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript in leetcode，and I'm doing the question reverse-linked-list in leetcode.
https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/.

I don't know what's the difference between my answer:

```
var h = new ListNode(head.val);
newReverseListTail.next = h;
```

and the correct answer.

```
head.next = null;
newReverseListTail.next = head;
```

when I use my answer,the result of the running program will just show the reserve of the last two listnode of the list,like:

input:[1,2,3,4,5,6]

my output:[6.5]

correct output:[6,5,4,3,2,1]

Here is all the code about the question.

```
var reverseList = function(head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null)  return head;
    let newReverseList = reverseList(head.next);
    let newReverseListTail = head.next;
    var h = new ListNode(head.val);
    head.next = null
    //newReverseListTail.next = h;
    newReverseListTail.next = head;
    head.next = null
    return newReverseList;
};
```

Comment: Can you share the full code which is not working? (Cannot tell you what's wrong but I like poking at things lol and it will make debugging easier :))

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution.

```js
    function reverse(A){
     let currentNode = A;
     let next, prev = null;
      while(currentNode){
       next = currentNode.next;
       currentNode.next = prev;
       prev = currentNode;
       currentNode = next;
    }
    console.log(prev);
    return prev;
  }

let data = {
  'data':1,
  'next':{
    'data':2,
    'next':{
      'data':3,
      'next':{
        'data':4,
        'next':null
      }
    }
  }
};

reverse(data); // 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```